# Move SDKs in Assets

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have installed **Firebase SDK** and now my **Assets** folder looks like this:

[image]

I don't want all of those files / folders to be stored at the **/Assets**. Can I move all of this stuff into some **"Assets/Third-party SDKs/"** folder? Is it fine to do that? I just don't want to break something accidentally.

p.s. I am asking about **SDKs** in general, not just **Firebase SDK**.

Comment: Depends on the SDK ... usually I general yes but some SDKs rely on a certain folder structure (e.g. Vuforia) so ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Special Folder Names in Unity.
You can read more about it [here.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html)

Some SDK's may load some files using [Resources.Load](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) and in this case if you change the folder location it may break, depending on the implementation. In this case you can just modify the paths accordingly.

I don't know how it works in Firebase SDK, but in most cases you should be fine. (Maybe there are some other cases in which some SDK's will stop working that I'm not aware of.)